# Javascript and Python JSON - variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, python, json

For example if you have the following JSON object(remove the semicolon for python):

```
values = {
    a: 1,
    b: {
        c: 2,
        d: { e: 3 }
    },
    f: 4,
    g: 5   
};
```

If you try to print `values` in JS, it will work fine. But in Python it will return an error `NameError: name 'a' is not defined` which means these variables aren't defined and needs to be set as strings.

Lets say I need to load it into python without manually converting these undefined variables to string. I tried `json.loads` but it didn't work. Any other built-in functions to do this work?
It seems in JS it automatically treats them as strings if they are not defined or just ignores the fact that they are defined or not?

Any explanation?

Comment: That's not JSON, that's a JS object.

Comment: Use JSON.stringify(values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried json.loads but it didn't work.

That's because what you've quoted isn't [JSON](http://json.org), it's a JavaScript object initializer being assigned to something (probably a variable).

Here's the equivalent JSON:

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": {
        "c": 2,
        "d": { "e": 3 }
    },
    "f": 4,
    "g": 5   
}
```

Items of note:

- No variable, no `=`
- The top level must be an object (e.g., `{...}`) or an array (e.g., `[...]`).
- Property names (keys) must be in double quotes
- Strings must be in double quotes (you don't have any strings in your example, but if you did, single quotes — for instance — wouldn't be valid)
- No `;` at the end

Comment: ah ok! I thought you can set it equal to a variable.